# Django GenericForeignKey using related_name

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

I'm trying to refactor my schema so that a field that is currently a simple `ForeignKey` becomes a `GenericForeignKey`. So, in my model, this:

```
ref_track = models.ForeignKey(Track, unique=False, related_name='posts_by_ref')
```

...becomes this:

```
ref_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
ref_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
ref_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('ref_content_type', 'ref_id')
```

Previously I was using `posts_by_ref` in a number of database queries, for example checking the submission status of the posts attached to a track (the post object is where the above fields are). However, I understand that `related_name` is not supported when using a `GenericForeignKey`, so is there another way to replicate this behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at [Reverse generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)